# python logging format: how to add bracket

Tags: python, logging

A quick question about Python logging format.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', format='%(levelname)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This will give me logging messages like:

```
INFO Test
```

What I want now is to add bracket to the level name, like:

```
[INFO] Test
```

How should I modify the format argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', format='[%(levelname)s] %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```